# No bin folder in community version of wso2 API Manager in gitlab

Tags: git, wso2, api-manager

I could not find the bin folder in Community version of WSO2 API Manager hence I could not start the server using file /bin/wso2sever.bat
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim
Am I missing something ?
Do I need to build the code to create bin file ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build the GitHub source code to use the API manager. **You can Download the latest WSO2 API Manager from here** https://wso2.com/api-management/ (this includes a bin folder and everything you were expected) and this is the [Documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/). If you want to modify some feature of the WSO2 API Manager, you can modify the GitHub source code and build your own pack.

Comment: I want to user the community edition which is available at https://github.com/wso2/product-apim . But as per instruction I need to run wso2servert.bat file under bin folder but this file is available at product-apim-master\modules\distribution\product\src\main\startup-scripts . But it gives following error:  "CARBON_HOME is set incorrectly or CARBON could not be located. Please set CARBON_HOME".

Comment: WSO2 API Manager is a fully open-source product and github.com/wso2/product-apim  includes the source code of the WSO2 API Manager. WSO2 website(what I mentioned above)  has hosted the product which is built from github.com/wso2/product-apim source code. So You can directly download it from the website([https://wso2.com/api-management/](https://wso2.com/api-management/) ) or GitHub releases. You don't need to worry about building source code to use it.

Comment: You can download from - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v3.2.0